# SpannableStringBuilder: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... -1) has end before start

Tags: android

I'm having a crash inside Android when using SpannableStringBuilder & TextView.

This crash doesn't happen often, but at times it does.

In the fragment, I update a textview with a SpannableStringBuilder object that is updated in a Service through a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData).

Below is java code, as well as logcat output + variable ouput in logcat.

How to fix this please?

I didn't find anything in google issuetracker, and didn't find the same error message on stackoverflow (some look similar, but still it's not exactly the same)

### Code

#### Fragment

```java
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

...

        textViewLog = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview_log);
        scrollview = ((NestedScrollView)  view.findViewById(R.id.scrollview));

        // Create the observer which updates the UI.
        final Observer<SpannableStringBuilder> ETAObserver = new Observer<SpannableStringBuilder>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final SpannableStringBuilder spannableLog) {
                // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String textViewLogStringBeforeUpdate = null;
                        if (BuildConfig.IS_TESTING.get()) {
                            // For Debug purposes: to try to understand this rare exception
                            // java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... -1) has end before start
                            textViewLogStringBeforeUpdate = textViewLog.getText().toString();
                        }
                        try {
                            textViewLog.setText(spannableLog);
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                            String msg = e.getMessage();
                            if (msg != null && msg.startsWith("setSpan")) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("ETATest", "Crash with message: " + msg);
                                Log.v("ETATest", "textViewLog Before: " + textViewLogStringBeforeUpdate);
                                Log.v("ETATest", "spannableLog: " + spannableLog);
                                Log.v("ETATest", "textViewLog After: " + textViewLog.getText());
                            } else {
                                throw e;
                            }
                        }
                        // Stuff that updates the UI
                        scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
        AddThumbsLogLiveData.get().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), ETAObserver);

    }
```

#### LogLiveData

```java
public class AddThumbsLogLiveData extends LiveData<SpannableStringBuilder> {
    private static AddThumbsLogLiveData sInstance;
    private final static SpannableStringBuilder log = new SpannableStringBuilder("");

    @MainThread
    public static AddThumbsLogLiveData get() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new AddThumbsLogLiveData();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private AddThumbsLogLiveData() {
    }

    public void appendLog(String text) {
        if (enableLog) Log.i(TAG, text);
        log.append(text);
        postValue(log);
    }

    public void appendLog(Spanned text) {
        if (enableLog) Log.i(TAG, text.toString());
        log.append(text);
        postValue(log);
    }

    public void clear() {
        log.clear();
    }
}
```

### Log

```
03-10 10:22:36.446 16047 16413 I ETALog  : Processing /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/test_standard_addThumbsSettingsDefaultTwoRuns
03-10 10:22:36.455 16047 16413 I ETALog  : Checking permissions…
03-10 10:22:36.458 16047 16413 I ETALog  :  Successful
03-10 10:22:36.460 16047 16047 W System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... -1) has end before start
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.checkRange(SpannableStringInternal.java:485)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:199)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.copySpansFromSpanned(SpannableStringInternal.java:87)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.<init>(SpannableStringInternal.java:48)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.text.SpannedString.<init>(SpannedString.java:35)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.text.SpannedString.<init>(SpannedString.java:44)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.text.TextUtils.stringOrSpannedString(TextUtils.java:532)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6318)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6227)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6179)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at com.exifthumbnailadder.app.AddThumbsFragment$4$1.run(AddThumbsFragment.java:162)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:7133)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at com.exifthumbnailadder.app.AddThumbsFragment$4.onChanged(AddThumbsFragment.java:152)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at com.exifthumbnailadder.app.AddThumbsFragment$4.onChanged(AddThumbsFragment.java:148)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:93)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
03-10 10:22:36.476 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 E ETATest : Crash with message: setSpan (0 ... -1) has end before start
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : textViewLog Before: Starting…
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking permission to access storage… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking permission to access storage… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking working directory permissions… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : 
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Processing /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/test_standard_addThumbsSettingsDefaultTwoRuns
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : spannableLog: Starting…
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking permission to access storage… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking permission to access storage… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking working directory permissions… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : 
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Processing /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/test_standard_addThumbsSettingsDefaultTwoRuns
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking permissions… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : textViewLog After: Starting…
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking permission to access storage… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking permission to access storage… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Checking working directory permissions… Successful
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : 
03-10 10:22:36.477 16047 16047 V ETATest : Processing /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/test_standard_addThumbsSettingsDefaultTwoRuns
```

Comment: The logcat message says the setSpan() method got a bad "end" parameter (-1) . You did not post that part of the code, go and check why there is a -1 in the method calll

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My input looks correct and I don't understand why there is this -1. The bug is actually in Android's code. I filed a bug report to Google.

Comment: Please check previously similar questions like this one. There's no line of code by looking at the log, but this bug is probably related to devices with accessibility and talkback enabled.